# Кодировка unichar в xCode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

У меня есть слово: NSString *str=@"Slovo";
Мне нужно разложить это слово на буквы и вывести на экран, я делаю так:

```
for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
NSLog(@"%c",[str characterAtIndex:i]); //Выводим букву на экран
}
```

Проблема в том, что это отлично работает только если в str записано английское слово, если str содержит русское или немецкое слово, то работает не правильно. 
   Подскажите как сделать чтобы правильно работало и для немецких, русских и французских слов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спецификатор %с не работает с UTF-8. [документация](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW2). Попробуйте разбить слово посредством -subStringFromRange: или чем-то для работы с объектными строками. Там у вас будет гарантированно UTF-8 и все символы будут нормально отображаться. Я так делал для приложений где есть буквы с диакритикой

Comment: Сейчас попробую так сделать

Comment: substringFromIndex - немного не подходит, она возвращает строку начиная с указанного элемента и до конца, сейчас поище еще какой-нибудь селектор в этом духе

Comment: subStringFromRange- вот то что нужно!!!

Comment: опечатался, это он)